# is mac good for python programming?

Tags: python, macos

I am programming a django based website. I actually use a small computer under Ubuntu 10.04.
I would like to buy something more professional, so I am wondering whether an iMac is good for that, because :

- Is there a free IDE as good as eclipse on MacOS ?
- Is there a remote python debugger like pydev for eclipse ?
- Is there some typical issues with python on MacOS ?
- does apache+mod_wsgi works well on MacOS ?

Comment: A Mac is just a PC now, so you can always put Ubuntu on it if you find it doesn't work out. Eclipse is available for OSX too.

Comment: Macs are one of the best development machines you can get since you can legally install Mac OS X, Windows and Linux all on the same machine. This allows for easy cross platform testing and with software like VMWare or VirtualBox, you can run all the OS's simultaneously.

Comment: a) There's nothing wrong with your current setup.  b) All of the things you're currently using on Ubuntu work on MacOS X - you don't need to find any equivalents.  Unless you care about some exotic feature in a Python version that isn't installed by default on the mac, the system python is fine (same for Ubuntu for that matter - you only get what the package manager decided to make)

Comment: Just do it :) , and go big if you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you consider iMac to be more or less professional than anything else? Hardware? System?
Note: I'm myself a MacOSX and Linux user.

Unless it's a requisite, most times I'd say it's only a matter of personal taste.

As said by others earlier, everything you cited works fine on MacOSX.

However, you should consider the 3rd party libraries you're going to use with Python.
I would cite a problem I had with MySQLdb (MySQL-python) on MacOSX, but it has been solved. You might face other problems in the way, but nothing that could stop you from using Django, Eclipse, etc.

Answer (score 5):

All of the things you mentioned (Eclipse+plugins, Python, Apache, mod_wsgi) can run fine on OS X.

Comment: That's an improvement - Eclipse was the only thing which could bring OS X down in the pre-intel days.

Comment: Eclipse ran on the Mac in the pre-Intel days.

Answer (score 4):

My answers based on several years spent developing with Python on OsX:

1. Eclipse is multiplatform, you can have it on OsX too.
2. I would not call pydev a python debugger, anyway you have it on Eclipse for Osx
3. You would have probably the same issues you had under Ubuntu (OsX is Unix based)
4. Yes it works without problem

One thing I always recommend is to install [macports](http://www.macports.org);
with macports installing Eclipse, different Python versions, apache, mod_wsgi is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, mod_wsgi is developed on MacOS X. My experience in supporting users of mod_wsgi is however that MacPorts and fink are an absolute PITA. Specifically, trying to use Python and Apache from those third party systems usually causes nothing but hurt. This is based on problems encountered over the last couple of years. I haven't heard much lately though, so it may be the case that those systems have finally fixed up their 32/64 bit issues and Python build problems.