# Python development under Mac

Tags: python, macos

I've been developing python web apps using django and appengine.
I'm planning on buying a macbook to develop iPhone apps.
I wonder if I will be able to develop my python apps without too much changes on a mac , or if keeping them on a PC will be better?

Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to do it? Mac OS X comes with Python anyway, although you might want to install a newer version. Define *without too much changes*. Imo Unix and Linux are much more suited for developing anyway (as long as your are not developing MS applications).

Comment: @Felix Kling, if anything you want to install an *older* version. Snow leopard comes with python 2.7, and app-engine runs on 2.5.

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: Mmh my version is 2.6.... anyway, I didn't know about app-engine and 2.5... sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is mac good for python programming ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080019/is-mac-good-for-python-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macs run Unix, Unix makes python development even easier! (IMHO)

In other news: one of python's big selling points is that it's multi-platform, it can run as well on Windows as on Linux as on a Mac.  Heck, here's a list of [other platforms](http://www.python.org/download/other/) it can run on.

All that to say, you can move your python projects back and forth between a mac and pc with relative ease as long as you don't use any platform specific libraries.  So, no you shouldn't have to do anything terribly special to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Developing python for app-engine on a mac works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Python development on a Mac will be similar to Python development on other *NIX-based operating systems which, in some ways, can be easier than on Windows.  As long as none of the modules you are using are Windows-only then you should have no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I usually develop with Python on OS X and it's a real pleasure to work it.
Just remember to install [Macports](http://www.macports.org);
with macports installing Python versions, Python libraries, Eclipse and so on is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Homebrew instead of MacPorts - [Link](https://brew.sh/)